# Change data table in datagridview when click button in vb. net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have 2 tables and what I want is when I click the 1st button, the first table will load in the Datagridview and when I click another 2nd button, it will load the other table.  But the thing is, I will only be using 1 Datagridview. Is this possible? I don't want to use another Datagridview view or another form. I want to use 1 datagridview in 1 form. Below is my data connection for loading to tables. I am using SQL Server.

```
 Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=IT-ASSISTANT\sqlexpress;Initial   Catalog=KIS;Integrated Security=True")
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
 Dim dt As New DataTable
```

[image]

table 1:

```
cn.Open()
With cmd
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "Select IDnumber as [ID Number], Productname as [Product 
                    Name], Brand, UnitPrice as [Unit Price], Stocks, UnitType as 
                   [Unit Type], ItemLocation as [Item Location], Remarks from 
                   MainForm"
End With
dt.Clear()
With da
    .SelectCommand = cmd
    .Fill(dt)
End With
DGVdata.DataSource = dt
cn.Close()
End Sub
```

table 2:

```
cn.Open()
With cmd
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "Select IDnumber as [ID Number], itmDescription as [Item  
                    Description], Supplier, UnitPrice as [Unit Price], Stocks, 
                    nsnumber as [Next Number], itemLoc as [Item Location], 
                    Remarks from FormsTable"
End With
dt.Clear()
With da
    .SelectCommand = cmd
    .Fill(dt)
End With
DGVdata.DataSource = dt
cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code should work? Just call them from different buttons

Comment: It is possible to change the datasource of the grid.

Comment: Yes, exactly as you're doing it. Are you having issues or getting errors?

Comment: I've finally solve the problem guys i replace my data table with dataset and calling two different table by ds.table(0) heheeh